# How to solve this second-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE for $c(x)$

$$2c(x)c''(x) - (c'(x))^2 = 0$$

to get the mentioned solution $c(x)=(Ax+B)^2$. By the way I checked for similar questions here but found them different because of the coefficient 2.

> Step 1: Rewrite the equation
> Let's denote $c(x)$ as $y'$ for simplicity. Then the equation becomes:
> $$2c(x)y' - y^2 = 0$$
> Step 2: Introduce a substitution
> We introduce a substitution by letting $u = c(x)$, which implies $y = u'$. The equation can be rewritten in terms of $u$
> $$2u u' - (u')^2 = 0$$
> Step 3: Solve the resulting differential equation
> Divide the equation by $u'$ to obtain:
> $$2u - u' = 0$$
> Rearranging terms gives:
> $$u' - 2u = 0$$
> Step 4: Integrate to find $c(x)$
> Exponentiating both sides yields:
> $$|u| = e^{2x + C_1}$$
> Since $u = c(x)$, we have:
> $$|c(x)| = e^{2x + C_1}$$
> Removing the absolute value gives two possible solutions:
> $$c(x) = e^{2x + C_1}$$ or $$c(x) = -e^{2x + C_1}$$

Where I stuck and couldn't get the mentioned solution

Comment: @JohnB It is just a typo, however, I couldn't reach the target solution!

Comment: This is a nonlinear ODE, so any method will have to be somewhat particular to this case. My own suggestion would be to let $b(x)=\ln c(x)$ and determine the form of the ODE satisfied by $b(x)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical Could you provide more details about your suggestion, please?

Comment: First, you have made a mistake in step 2. The substitution you mention would only return the original ODE but in $u$ instead of $c$. The suggestion @Semiclassical gives is, in my opinion, the nicest way forward, you will get a more appealing nonlinear ODE in $b$ that eventuates, after another substitution, to a separable ODE.

Answer (score 5):

Since $(Ax+B)^2$ has degree at most $2$, it is reasonable to compute $c'''$. Indeed we have
$$
c'''=\left(\frac{(c')^2}{2c}\right)'=\frac{4cc'c''-2(c')^3}{4c^2}
=2c'\frac{2cc''-(c')^2}{4c^2}=0.
$$
Therefore,
$$
c(x)=c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3
$$
for some constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$. Substituting in the original equation gives
$$
0=2(c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3)2c_1-(2c_1x+c_2)^2=-c_2^2 + 4 c_1 c_3.
$$
Writing $c_1=A^2$ and $c_3=B^2$ we find that $$c_2^2=4c_1c_3=4A^2B^2$$ and so $c_2=2AB$ and
$$
c(x)=c_1x^2+c_2x+c_3=A^2x^2+2ABx+B^2=(Ax+B)^2.
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$2c(x)c''(x) - (c'(x))^2 = 0$$
Note that $c=\text {constant}$ is a solution.
$$2\dfrac {c''}{c'} - \dfrac {c'}{c} = 0$$
$$(2\ln {c'})' -(\ln c)' = 0$$
$$\left(\ln \dfrac  {c'^2}{c} \right)'  = 0$$

Comment: Yes after integration @MathLover

Comment: I got it thanks

Comment: You're welcome @MathLover

Answer (score 1):

The approach that you were probably trying to imitate was to set $c'(x)=u(c(x))$ wherever such a substitution is applicable. Then $c''=uu'$ and
$$
0=2cuu'-u^2=c^2(c^{-1}u(c)^{2})'
$$
This gives $c'(x)^2=Ac(x)$ etc.